# How to Update Newly Added Lookup Column using Value from the existing Choice column through powershell

Tags: powershell, document-library, lookup-column, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I am working with SharePoint on prem 2019 and in one of the document libraries, I have a field called 'Trust' of type choice, this library contains about 7000 files. 
Now we have to convert this choice field into a lookup column and I am aware its not doable OOTB.

So we added all choice values for Trust field into a list (titled 'Trust List') on the same subsite where  the library resides. Then created a site lookup column 'TrustName' that points to the title field of Trust list and added it to the library as well.

Now I need to find a solution to sort of grab Trust (choice) value for each row and paste it into the TrustName (lookup), maybe there would be need of filtering of ID from lookup list based on the match of values of 'Trust' field and Title from lookup list, not sure, I have little expertise in powershell. So looking for a PowerShell script solution for this that I can run. FYI, there are 3 other lookup fields in the same library, couple of text fields, people picker etc.

Please help, thanks in advance. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can help you.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue

$mySiteUrl = "https://some_portal/sites/yoursite"
$myList = "Some Library"

#lookup list name
$myListLU = "Lookup List"

$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $mySiteUrl
$web = $spSite.OpenWeb()

# Retrieve the lists
$list = $web.GetList($myList)
$listLU = $web.GetList($myListLU)

# Enumerate the list and update column
$itemCount = $list.Items.Count
ForEach ($item in $list.Items) {
  $choiceValue = $item["choiceColumn"]
  #get matching item from lookup list
  $lookupItem = $listLU.Items | where { $_['columnNameInLookUpList'] -eq $choiceValue }

  #fill the fetched item into new lookup column
  $NewLookupFieldValue = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPFieldLookupValue $lookupItem["ID"], $lookupItem["columnNameInLookUpList"]
      $item["newLookupColumn"] = $NewLookupFieldValue
      $item.Update()
}
$web.Dispose()
```

Please try executing where SharePoint is installed and let me know if any errors.

Comment: Thank you so much Harshal for a quick response, I am going to try this shortly and let you know.

Comment: Hey harshal, i guess there are couple of unexpected parenthesis at the end, can you check please. Also on the dev machine/en, when I opened SP 2019 management shell as admin, I see a message: "the local farm is not accessible, CMDlests with feature dependecyID are not registered. " the message comes up first before running any script. However I don't see that on production when SP19 management shell is launched. Any thoughts? Dev is single server farm and different user account is used than prod. FYI.

Comment: Open it as farm account and then try. Please adjust the parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks Harshal, I am using farm account only

Comment: Try running it as admin. Still if you get the same error, then try running this Add-SPShellAdmin -username DOMAIN\YourUser

Comment: Thanks, I did run it as admin earlier so I ran the snippet you mentioned. Now I am getting: You need to have Machine administrator priviliges to run this cmdlet. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, I am running this now on my machine, getting an error on getlist, please see screenshot in question description.

Comment: Try the updated code. Try both internal or display name. Check which one works.

Comment: Thanks, getting same error on $listLU, for me internal and display name are same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99214/discussion-between-mdevm-and-harshal-gite).